# Windows command line - get pdf page width and height in pixels?

Tags: windows, command-line, pdf, metadata, pixels

I need a piece of software (a freeware preferably) that will display what is the pixel width / height of a pdf page. If there are many pages with different dimensions, I'd be enough to just get the first page dimensions. I've tested pdftk and it appears that the program lacks the feature I want.

Answer (score 2):

There is a GPL licensed binary compiled for Windows, here:

http://www.xpdfreader.com/download.html

See in the Xpdf package download, the utility `pdfinfo`.

To get the pdf size, call it like this:

```
pdfinfo your-pdf-file.pdf
```

NOTE: `pdfinfo` along with other utilities is also included in another package, available from here (only compiled for 32bit):

https://blog.alivate.com.au/poppler-windows/

The latest version as of today is: [poppler-0.68.0_x86](https://blog.alivate.com.au/wp-content/uploads/2018/10/poppler-0.68.0_x86.7z)

Answer (score 1):

One solution would be to convert the PDF into pictures and then get width and height of the pictures. For conversion I used [PDF-Viewer](http://www.tracker-software.com/product/pdf-xchange-viewer) and for getting width and height identify from [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/). You might want to use convert from ImageMagick to do it completely from command line, however this did not succeed here.

C:\Users\gentlesea\Documents\PDFToImageTest>identify test.png
test.png PNG 2479x3508 2479x3508+0+0 8-bit DirectClass 186KB 0.000u 0:00.000